# Special TranslateAnimation in Android

Tags: android, translate-animation

I coded a TranslateAnimation for my Android App.

Now I want it to look more "special"

[image]

I found this in the www.

Is there any possibility to translate it that way?

If my specific view is moved by the TranslateAnimation, I would like to have such an effect like for example the first tennisball-movement.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Look at my edit. I hope it works.

Comment: Would you like to left "shadows" behind your moving View?

Comment: exactly. If "shadow" is the right word ;)

Comment: The Animation itslf is easy to replicate. What is not is the "ghost" effect. You cannot do this just by using an animation.